# QlikSense expression to only show the products selected in the codes

Tags: qliksense

I just started QlikSense a few weeks ago, and am currently stuck on counting fields with more than 1 criteria, I've searched around in the discussion forums and can't seem to find any solution to this.

Basically, I wanted to generate an expression that only shows the my New Customers in 2017, for my targeted products, the end table should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcKaH.png)
For this, i have thought of an expression that takes in only customers that had bought from us in 2017(invoice amount > 0), and not in 2016(invoice amount=0), for the targeted products, but I cant seem to go about coding the expression for it.

The tables which i currently use is:
-Invoice details table(which includes all the invoice details of all customers buying, for all products,across years 2015-2017, along with the amount$ paid in the invoice)
-Targeted Products table(products which we have to look at, which is "Product A", "Product B", "Product C")

The following is the expression which I have done up so far, but instead of showing new customers, it's also showing customers that are not buying from us.

```
count(
aggr(
sum(
{$<[Invoice Date.autoCalendar.Year]={"2017"},
[Product-Product Name (Finance File)]={
"Product A", "Product B", "Product C"
}
>}
[Amount$]
)
, CUSTOMER_CODE
)>0
AND
aggr(
sum(
{$<[Invoice Date.autoCalendar.Year]={"2016"},
[Product-Product Name (Finance File)]={
"Product A", "Product B", "Product C"
}
>}
[Amount$]
)
, CUSTOMER_CODE
)=0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a good idea of your table structure. I hope you are using Master Calendar in script and your invoice date is linked to that of the Master Calendar.

To keep things simple, I created an example dataset

[image]

Our target product is B and we want to capture its sales for new customer C. I used the expression:

```
Sum({


<

    Customer    =   {"=Sum({<Year = {2017}>}Sales)"}

    , Product = {'B'}



>




    }Sales)
```

This expression can be used in a straight table such as the below one:

[image]

I used A,B,C for both customers and products but they are not related - my sloppiness!

---

If you want to know who are the new customers that bought Product 'B' in 2017, then you can use the following expression:

Count({

<

```
Customer    =   {"=Sum({<Year = {2017}>}Sales)"}

, Product = {'B'}
```

>

-

<

```
Customer    =   {"=Sum({<Year = {2016}>}Sales)"}
```

>

```
}Distinct Customer)
```

Comment: Hi Kundan, thank you for your reply! However, I think that you have interpreted my question wrongly. I wanted to display just the product and the no. of new customers that brought the product. I have inserted the image as an example of what I wanted to display in the main question.

Comment: The new expression should work as you asked for. Let me know if this works